# How to create a species accumulation curve by hand?

Tags: environmental-protection

In my Environmental Science class, we were given this data with the sample # and abundance given. I would have to solve for relative abundance, which is finished below:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
Taxa & \text{Sample #} & \text{Abundance} & \text{Relative Abundance} \\
\hline
A & 1 & 100 & 0.71 \\
B & 2 & 20 & 0.14 \\
C & 5 & 5 & 0.04 \\
D & 59 & 8 & 0.06 \\
E & 150 & 2 & 0.01 \\
F & 223 & 1 & 0.01 \\
G & 257 & 2 & 0.01 \\
H & 400 & 2 & 0.01 \\
\end{array}
$$

The sum of the abundance is 140, which was used to find the relative abundance. With this data, I know how to make a rank abundance curve, but I do not understand how to make a species accumulation curve. This is the finished species accumulation curve shown in class:

[image: species accumulation curve]

I do not understand this graph and I would like some help in interpreting it because I would need to be able to make a species accumulation curve of my own by hand. Preferably, I would like some help in how to plot it with the data I was given. Thank you!